# Como calcular um FOR para de 6 em 6 incrementos ele dar um echo?

Tags: php, matemática, for

Tenho um FOR simples que preciso que a cada 6 incrementos ele mande um echo com uma mensagem, segue código:

```
$carros = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Alfa Romeu", "WV", "Teste", "test2", "Teste4", "Teste3", "Teste5", "Volkswagem", "Ferrari");

for ($i=0; $i < count($carros); $i++) {
    echo "Carro ".$carros[$i];

    //quando chegar a 6, 12, 18, 24, 30... ele manda esse echo
    echo "Página: ".$i;

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

coloque um IF com uma condição verificando se o seu contador é um múltiplo de 6.

```
$carros = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Alfa Romeu", "WV", "Teste", "test2", "Teste4", "Teste3", "Teste5", "Volkswagem", "Ferrari");

for ($i=0; $i < count($carros); $i++) {
    echo "Carro ".$carros[$i];

    if ($i%6 === 0){
      echo "Página: ".$i;
    }
}
```

Comment: mande exemplos de código...

Comment: Editei a resposta, usando sua propria logica do FOR e adicionando o if com a verificação. Fazendo um 'MOD' do valor do contador com o 6, se o resultado é 0, significa que o numero é múltiplo de 6, e assim vai imprimir a sequencia que deseja.  @AlanPS

Answer (score 3):

Pode verificar se o `$i` é mod (que verifica se a divisão não tem resto) de 6 então imprimir o número de página.

```
if($i % 6 === 0) echo $i;
```

Outro exemplo simples:

```
foreach(range(1, 60 ) as $item){
    if($item % 6 === 0) echo 'Página '. $item .PHP_EOL;
}
```

Saída:

```
Página 6
Página 12
Página 18
Página 24
Página 30
Página 36
Página 42
Página 48
Página 54
Página 60
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/XsGgNR)

Answer (score 3):

```
$carros = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota", "Alfa Romeu", "WV", "Teste", "test2", "Teste4", "Teste3", "Teste5", "Volkswagem", "Ferrari");

for ($i=0; $i < count($carros); $i++) {
echo "Carro ".$carros[$i];

$number = 0;
if($i === (6 + number)){
    number = number + 6;
    echo "Página: ".$i;
 }
}
```